# Throttle CPU usage on background thread

Tags: objective-c, scenekit

I have a CPU intensive task and I want it to use less CPU and take up more time.

I'm loading a massive amount of SCNNodes to a scene at start-up. It takes up a lot of memory, and I'd like it to work on it at a safe rate instead of lagging up my system or potentially crashing it.

Here's the code I'm using to load the nodes.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void){
    NSLog(@"Start Loading Level");
    SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
    cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
    cameraNode.camera.zFar = 5000;
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 3000, 0);
    cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, -M_PI_2);
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        int side = 3000;
        SCNNode *node = [SCNNode node];
        node.geometry = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:1 height:1 length:1 chamferRadius:0];
        node.position = SCNVector3Make(arc4random_uniform(side) - side / 2.0,
                                       0,
                                       arc4random_uniform(side) - side / 2.0);
        [scene.rootNode addChildNode:node];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        NSLog(@"Finished");
    });
});
```

Here are the statistics:

[image: Image Usage over Time]
[image: Image Memory]

Comment: I would be more preoccupied by the fact that SceneKit will have to render so many nodes. 100000 nodes is incredibly huge.

Comment: This is a test case. I could use code from my own project, but this seems to get the point across.

Comment: I would suggest using dispatch_apply() with stride instead of for(;;) inside dispatch_async() to concurrently create nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it doesn't help at all when it comes to cpu usage.

Comment: Are you sure it won't automatically use the right amount of less time as soon as you have some competing tasks?  If so, you could try periodic calls to usleep() or sched_yield, though not sure how those interact with GCD.

Comment: Well, given enough cubes it'll use up enough memory and crash the application. I'm trying to find how how to load up a preset level in SceneKit in the background without lagging the system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might not be the best way to do this, but have you looked at `prepareobject:`?

Creating the NSObjects themselves shouldn't be that much of a problem, but preparing the geometry and adding it to the scene probably is. Bu deffering this step to a secondary thread you'll save some CPU and make the scene not stop until the node is ready to be added.

Once each node is ready, (completion handler) just add it to the scene. I won't throttle the loading, but it will at least handle it in a safer way for the rest of your app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRenderer/prepareObjects:withCompletionHandler:

```
-(void)prepareLevel{
    // Mutable Array to save the nodes
    NSMutableArray *nodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        int side = 3000;
        SCNNode *node = [SCNNode node];
        node.geometry = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:1 height:1 
                                      length:1 chamferRadius:0];
        node.position = SCNVector3Make(arc4random_uniform(side) - side / 2.0,
                                       0,
                                       arc4random_uniform(side) - side / 2.0);

        [nodes addObject:node];
    }

    [mySCNView prepareObjects:nodes withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        for(SCNNode*node in nodes){
            [scene.rootNode addChildNode:node];
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: This did fix my problem, thank you.
Could you edit your answer with a piece of example code?

Comment: Sure, I'll do that when I get home.

Comment: I added a simple code sample. There is still room for optimisation but it show the basic usage of `prepareObject:`

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you very much. I requested it more for people who would view the question later on, as sample code is very helpful for these types of questions.

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas:

1. Use NSOperationQueue, it has the method setThreadPriority: which can be used to throttle the load to some extend.
2. Because you are dispatching on an asynchronous queue, maybe you can insert a sleep() function after processing every 100th Element or so. This should reduce the amount of work for the processor because the thread stalls for some percentage of the time, but it won't make your UI laggy, because its just a background queue.

Obviously this is going to sacrifice CPU load for execution time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not doing anything to limit the number of simultaneous operations. Doing this is probably going to be more effective than trying to throttle CPU usage as CPU usage throttling is a vague concept by comparison.

To limit the number of concurrent operations, you can do one of the following:

1. Make a custom `dispatch_queue` using `dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.loadQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)`. `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` prevents blocks in the queue from running concurrently.
2. As @JoJoe mentioned in their answer, use an `NSOperationQueue`. I'd suggest using `setConcurrentOperationCount:` rather than `setThreadPriority:` to limit the number of concurrent operations. If you don't want to bother with setting up your own `NSOperation` subclass you can use `NSBlockOperation`.