# How to add SCNNodes without blocking main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, swift3, scenekit

I'm creating and adding a large number of SCNNodes to a SceneKit scene, which causes the app to freeze for a second or two.

I thought I could fix this by putting all the action in a background thread using `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async()`, but no dice. It behaves exactly the same.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29758556/149097) and put the nodes through [`SCNView.prepare()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522798-prepare) before adding them, hoping it would slow down the background thread and prevent blocking. It didn't.

Here's a test function that reproduces the problem:

```
func spawnNodesInBackground() {
    // put all the action in a background thread
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        var nodes = [SCNNode]()
        for i in 0...5000 {
            // create a simple SCNNode
            let node = SCNNode()
            node.position = SCNVector3(i, i, i)
            let geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
            geometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white.cgColor
            node.geometry = geometry
            nodes.append(node)
        }
        // run the nodes through prepare()
        self.mySCNView.prepare(nodes, completionHandler: { (Bool) in
            // nodes are prepared, add them to scene
            for node in nodes {
                self.myRootNode.addChildNode(node)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When I call `spawnNodesInBackground()` I expect the scene to continue rendering normally (perhaps at a reduced frame rate) while new nodes are added at whatever pace the CPU is comfortable with. Instead the app freezes completely for a second or two, then all the new nodes appear at once.

Why is this happening, and how can I add a large number of nodes without blocking the main thread?

Comment: What about separating each SCNNode addition as its own task added to the queue ? Then you let the system decide when it want to execute each task. Right now, you create one big task that adds 5000 nodes instead of creating 5000 tasks that each add one node. There is no possible concurrency in this scenario.

Comment: The concurrency he's asking for is to reduce/eliminate the freeze on the main (UI) thread. Doing the all of the node creation on one background thread is fine. The freeze happens at the `prepare()` and `addChildNode()` calls.

Comment: Have you tried adding all of the new nodes to a single parent the node in your background thread, then add that node to the root node with a single call to addChildNode()?

Comment: @ScottAhten I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't remove or reduce the blocking.

Comment: @KarlSigiscar I tried your suggestion. When the tasks were added to the queue asynchronously, it spawned 74 threads before crashing. When added synchronously, there was no reduction in blocking.

Comment: @robert I also noticed that you were accessing the scene kit view (which is a UIView subclass) in a background thread. Normally, UIKit classes are not thread safe and this could have undesired consequences. Nor could I find any documentation that explicitly indicated it was thread safe. Prepare has it's own background thread, so you shouldn't need to call it from another background thread. Try wrapping that call in `dispatch_async` with the main queue or switching to `SCNRenderer`.

Comment: @ScottAhten The documentation doesn't say, but my impression is that SceneKit has its own private thread(s), and that any changes get batched to that thread regardless of what thread they were called from. At least that's how it seems to behave. Whether I call `prepare` from the main thread or a background thread, or leave it out entirely, I get the same behavior.

Comment: @robert: can you show the asynchronous code spawning 74 threads ?

Comment: @Robert While SceneKit's renderer does have its own private threads, this does not guarantee methods on SKView won't call UIView superclass methods before dispatching work on those threads or other non-UIKit SK classes. While it's convenient to use SKView, since it abstracts much of the details for you, those details let you better identify the bottleneck. SKRenderer might be a better choice, along with an Open GL / Metal view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this problem is solvable using the DispatchQueue. If I substitute some other task instead of creating `SCNNode`s it works as expected, so I think the problem is related to SceneKit.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700071/scenekit-threads-what-to-do-on-which-thread) suggest that SceneKit has its own private background thread that it batches all changes to. So regardless of what thread I use to create my `SCNNodes`, they all end up in the same queue in the same thread as the render loop.

The ugly workaround I'm using is to add the nodes a few at a time in SceneKit's delegated `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)` method until they're all done.

Comment: Nice hack! Any tips on geometry or resource limits to add per frame?

Comment: @HalMueller I'm still using spheres. I settled on 10 per frame, which gets 60fps easily on a 6s. It takes a bit over 8 seconds to add all 5000 nodes, but that's fine for my application. I add the biggest nodes first, so it's less noticeable that little ones are still appearing.

Answer (score 2):

I poked around on this and didn't solve the freeze (I did reduce it a bit).

I expect that `prepare()` is going to exacerbate the freeze, not reduce it, because it's going to load all resources into the GPU immediately, instead of letting them be lazily loaded. I don't think you need to call `prepare()` from a background thread, because the doc says it already uses a background thread. But creating the nodes on a background thread is a good move.

I did see pretty good performance improvement by moving the `geometry` outside the loop, and by using a temporary parent node (which is then cloned), so that there's only one call to add a new child to the scene's root node. I also reduced the sphere's segment count to 10 (from the default of 48).

I started with the spinning spaceship sample project, and triggered the addition of the spheres from the tap gesture. Before my changes, I saw 11 fps, 7410 draw calls per frame, 8.18M triangles. After moving the geometry out of the loop and flattening the sphere tree, I hit 60 fps, with only 3 draw calls per frame and 1.67M triangles (iPhone 6s).

Do you need to build these objects at run time? You could build this scene once, archive it, and then embed it as an asset. Depending on the effect you want to achieve, you might also consider using SCNSceneRenderer's `present(_:with:incomingPointOfView:transition:completionHandler)` to replace the entire scene at once.

```
func spawnNodesInBackgroundClone() {
    print(Date(), "starting")
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let tempParentNode = SCNNode()
        tempParentNode.name = "spheres"
        let geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.4)
        geometry.segmentCount = 10
        geometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green.cgColor
        for x in -10...10 {
            for y in -10...10 {
                for z in 0...20 {
                    let node = SCNNode()
                    node.position = SCNVector3(x, y, -z)
                    node.geometry = geometry
                    tempParentNode.addChildNode(node)
                }
            }
        }
        print(Date(), "cloning")
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
        let cloneNode = tempParentNode.flattenedClone()
        print(Date(), "adding")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(Date(), "main queue")
            print(Date(), "prepare()")
            scnView.prepare([cloneNode], completionHandler: { (Bool) in
                scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cloneNode)
                print(Date(), "added")
            })
            // only do this once, on the simulator
            // let sceneData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: scnView.scene!)
            // try! sceneData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/hal/scene.scn"))
            print(Date(), "queued")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful suggestions! Unfortunately in my actual use case, the `geometry` is different for each sphere, so that must remain in the loop. The temporary parent node could work for me so I'll try that. And I like your suggestion about using an archived asset, although I feel like this is something that should be doable live.

Comment: Can definitely do this live. It's a question of how much freeze and how tolerant you are of it. Since you're already creating on a background thread, using an archived scene won't (I predict) affect transition time much. You're adding 8M triangles, and that will take time no matter how they're made! `present(...)` approach could help you, fooling the user (with a fade or flip, rather than a freeze). `SCNLevelOfDetail` probably won't help because you're still adding a bunch of geometry at once. Can you reduce segment count, or use pyramids instead? Reducing from 7400 to 3 draw calls was huge.

Answer (score 1):

I have an asteroid simulation with 10000 nodes and ran into this issue myself. What worked for me was creating the container node, then passing it to a background process to fill it with child nodes.

That background process uses an SCNAction on that container node to add each of the generated asteroids to the container node.

```
let action = runBlock { 
    Container in
    // generate nodes
    /// then For each node in generatedNodes
    Container.addChildNode(node)
}
```

I also used a shared level of detail node with an uneven sided block as its geometry so that the scene can draw those nodes in a single pass.

I also pre-generate 50 asteroid shapes that get random transformations applied during the background generation process. That process simply has to grab at random a pregen block apply a random simd transformation then stored for adding scene later.

I’m considering using a pyramid for the LOD but the 5 x 10 x 15 block works for my purpose. Also this method can be easily throttled to only add a set amount of blocks at a time by creating and passing multiple actions to the node. Initially I passed each node as an action but this way works too.

Showing the entire field of 10000 still affects the FPS slightly by 10 a 20 FPS but At that point the container nodes own LOD comes into effect showing a single ring.

Answer (score 0):

Add all of them when application started but position them where camera dont see. When you need them change their position where they should be.